# How to open an iPhone compatible M3U file on Windows?

Tags: itunes, iphone, streaming, vlc-media-player, playlists

This is how the M3U file looks like:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1400000
http://maskedip/http_livestr.str?r=true&id=mbit-test&k=testkey
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=900000
http://maskedip/http_livestr.str?r=true&id=test&k=testkey
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=450000
http://maskedip/http_livestr.str?r=true&id=mobile-test&k=testkey
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,CODECS="mp4a.40.2",BANDWIDTH=64000
http://maskedup/http_livestr.str?r=true&id=test-audio&k=testkey
```

Clicking on 
http://maskedip/http_livestr.str?r=true&id=mbit-test&k=testkey then returns another M3U file in this format:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:1361
#EXTINF:10,
http://maskedip/http_ls/testkey/mbit-test1/1361.ts
#EXTINF:10,
http://maskedip/http_ls/testkey/mbit-test1/1362.ts
#EXTINF:10,
http://maskedip/http_ls/testkey/mbit-test1/1363.ts
#EXTINF:10,
http://maskedip/http_ls/testkey/mbit-test1/1364.ts
#EXTINF:10,
http://maskedip/http_ls/testkey/mbit-test1/1365.ts
#EXTINF:10,
http://maskedip/http_ls/testkey/mbit-test1/1366.ts
#EXTINF:10,
http://maskedip/http_ls/testkey/mbit-test1/1367.ts
#EXTINF:10,
http://maskedip/http_ls/testkey/mbit-test1/1368.ts
#EXTINF:10,
http://maskedip/http_ls/testkey/mbit-test1/1369.ts
```

Anyways, VLC won't recognize it. How can I play this on the PC?

Answer (score 0):

Windows Media Player can play m3u files, if it does not play, install [KLite-Codec Pack](http://www.filehippo.com/download_klite_codec_pack/)